# How to count the number of times a string appears?

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this

```
PT <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
visit <- c("w1","w2","w3","w4","w1","w2","w3","w1","w2","w3","w4","w5")
dose_level <- c("250", "250", "200", "200", "250", "250", "250", "200","200","150", "150", "100")
test <- data.frame(PT, visit, dose_level)
```

What I want to do is to calculate the number of times dose-level reduction by each patient. 
The result would be like:

[image]

Thank you in advance. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Is the `times` in row 3 right? Shouldn't it be 2?

Comment: Thank you @RuiBarradas Yes, you are right. It should be 2. I made a mistake here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R this can be done with `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(dose_level ~ PT, test, function(x){
  y <- as.integer(as.character(x))
  sum(diff(y) < 0)
})
#  PT dose_level
#1  1          1
#2  2          0
#3  3          2
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess patient 3 should be 2?

```r
PT <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
visit <- c("w1","w2","w3","w4","w1","w2","w3","w1","w2","w3","w4","w5")
dose_level <- c("250", "250", "200", "200", "250", "250", "250", "200","200","150", "150", "100")
test <- data.frame(PT,visit, dose_level)

library(data.table)
setDT(test)[,.(times=sum(dose_level<shift(dose_level),na.rm = TRUE)),by=.(PT)]
#>    PT times
#> 1:  1     1
#> 2:  2     0
#> 3:  3     2
```

Comment: Thanks you Frank. Your are correct. It should be 2. I appreciate your option using data.table. Please bear with me I can only give one best answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
test <- data.table(test)
test[,dose_level:=as.numeric(as.character(dose_level))]
test[,lag:=shift(dose_level,1),by="PT"]
#calculate difference between actual and lag
test[,diff:=dose_level-lag]
#flag to check if the diff is +ve or -ve 
test[,check:=ifelse(diff<0,1,0)]
test_summarise <- test[,.(sum(check,na.rm=T)),by="PT"]
test_summarise
PT V1
1  1
2  0
3  2
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your solution

Answer (score 0):

Base R one (obfuscated) liner:

```
data.frame(PT = unique(PT),
  times = sapply(split(test, test$PT), function(x){sum(c(FALSE, abs(diff(as.numeric(x$dose_level))) > 0))}))
```